# R Extract specific text from column into multiple columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe exported from the web with this format

```
id vals
1  {7,12,58,1}
2  {1,2,5,7}  
3  {15,12}
```

I would like to extract ONLY the numbers (ignore curlys and commas) into multiple columns like this

```
id val_1 val_2 val_3 val_4 val_5
1  7     12    58    1
2  1     2     5     7  
3  15    12
```

Even though the Max of values we got was 4 I want to always go up to value val_5.

Thanks!

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the input as it is not clear about the structure of 'vals'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible `tidyverse` option, where we remove the curly brackets, then separate the rows on the `,`, then pivot to wide form. Then, we can create the additional column (using `add_column` from `tibble`) based on the max value in the column names (which is 4 in this case), and then can create `val_5`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(vals = str_replace_all(vals, "\\{|\\}", "")) %>%
  separate_rows(vals, sep=",") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ind, values_from = vals, names_prefix = "val_") %>%
  add_column(!!(paste0("val_", parse_number(names(.)[ncol(.)])+1)) := NA)
```

**Output**

```
  id val_1 val_2 val_3 val_4 val_5
1  1     7    12    58     1    NA
2  2     1     2     5     7    NA
3  3    15    12  <NA>  <NA>    NA
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "id vals
1  {7,12,58,1}
2  {1,2,5,7}
3  {15,12} ", header = T)
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `str_extract_all` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(vals = str_extract_all(vals, '\\d+', ''))
```

or as @akrun suggest in the comments

```
df %>% 
  mutate(vals = str_extract_all(vals, '\\d+', '')) %>% 
  do.call(data.frame, .)
```

```
  id vals.1 vals.2 vals.3 vals.4
1  1      7     12     58      1
2  2      1      2      5      7
3  3     15     12   <NA>   <NA>
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, vals = c("{7,12,58,1}", "{1,2,5,7}", 
"{15,12}")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
result <- setDT(df)[, stri_match_all_regex(vals, '\\d+')[[1]], by=.(id)]
result[, item:=paste('val', 1:.N, sep='_'), by=.(id)]   # defines column names
dcast(result, id~item, value.var = 'V1')                # convert from long to wide
##    id val_1 val_2 val_3 val_4
## 1:  1     7    12    58     1
## 2:  2     1     2     5     7
## 3:  3    15    12  <NA>  <NA>
```